# Using Sum with Last mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

UseCase: I have the following data:

```
{"accountNumber":"1-1", "details":["version":{ "number": "1","accountGroup":"1", "editable":"false" , "amount":100 }]}
{"accountNumber":"1-2", "details":[version":{ "number": "2", "accountGroup":"1", "editable":"false" ,  "amount":200}]}
{"accountNumber":"2-1", "details":[version":{ "number": "1", "accountGroup":"2", "editable":"false",  "amount":200 }]}
```

Where: my document is *account*. Each record has a *accountGroup* (1, 2). A group can have multiple versions. AccountNumber is being initialized by the combination of AccountGroup & version

I want to get the **latest version** of the account **(accountNumber 1-2 & 2-1)** along with the sum of their amount.

**Expected output:**

```
{accountNumber:2-1}, {accountNumber: 1-2}, total: 400 (sum of amount of the latest versions of the account group)
```

I am using the following query:

```
db.getCollection('account').aggregate([
{ "$sort": { "accountNumber": 1 } },
{ "$unwind": "$details"},
 { "$group": {    

     "_id": "$details.version.accountGroup",
    "Latestversion": { "$last": "$$ROOT" },
    "total": { 
        $sum: "$details.version.amount" 
    } 
}

}])
```

It gets the sum of the all the versions which belongs to a group.

**Current output:**

```
{"accountNumber": "1-2", total: 300}, {"accountNumber":"2-1", total: 200}
```

I am new to Mongodb, any help is appreciated. Looking forward for a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two `$group` stages.

First `$group` to find the latest document for each `account group` and second `$group` to sum `amount` from latest document.

Something like

```
aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "accountNumber": 1 } },
  { "$unwind": "$details"},
  { "$group": {    
      "_id": "$details.version.accountGroup",
       "latest": { "$last": "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { "$group": {    
       "_id": null,
       "accountNumbers": { $push:"$latest.accountNumber" },
       "total": { $sum: "$latest.details.version.amount" } 
    }
  }
])
```

You can update your structure to below and remove `$unwind`.

```
{"accountNumber":"1-1", detail:{"number": "1","accountGroup":"1", "editable":"false" , "amount":100 }}
```

Comment: Thanks, this rocks.